# Getting a ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import from a particular module

Tags: python, python-import

The directory I have looks like this:

```
repository
  /src
    /main.py
    /a.py
    /b.py
    /c.py
```

I run my program via `python ./main.py` and within `main.py` there's an important statement `from a import some_func`. I'm getting a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'` every time I run the program.

I've tried running the Python shell and running the commands `import b` or `import c` and those work without any errors. There's nothing particularly special about `a` either, it just contains a few functions.

What's the problem and how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using a relative import, which allows you to import modules from other directories relative to the location of the current file.

Note that you will need to add a dot (.) before the module name when using a relative import, this indicates that the module is in the same directory as the current file:

```
from . import a
```

Or try running it from a different directory and appending the /src path like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/src')
```

You could also try using the PYTHONPATH (environment variable) to add a directory to the search path:

- Open your terminal and navigate to the directory containing the main.py file (/src).
- Set the PYTHONPATH environment variable to include the current directory, by running the following command
  `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$(pwd)`

At last you could try to use the -m flag inside your command, so that Python knows to look for the a module inside the /src directory:

```
python -m src.main
```

Comment: I've actually tried the first solution and that gives me a `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` and the second solution still gives me the same error. :(

Comment: You are probably getting the error above because Python cannot determine the correct package to use as the base for the relative import. i.e., a module that is not inside a directory with an `__init__.py `file

Comment: I've tried adding an empty `__init__.py` file before posting this question but it still didn't work. Do I need to populate the `__init__.py` file?

Comment: No, at least not that I'm aware

Comment: Maybe try it like this way: `import src.a` This will import the module from the /src directory, without using a relative import, but still specifying the path?

Comment: Sorry to keep shooting you down, but I've also tried that. When I tried that I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`...

Comment: Wilde guess, but maybe you need to specify the -m flag in your command because you are using dot (.) notation to run your script?

Answer (score 0):

```
repository/
  __init__.py
  /src
  __init__.py
  main.py
  a.py
  b.py
  c.py
```

In the `__init__.py` in `repository`, add the following line:

```
from . import repository
```

In the `__init__.py` in `src`, add the following line:

```
from . import main
from . import a
from . import b
from . import c
```

Now `from src.a import your_func` is going to work on `main.py`

Comment: Sorry but this didn't work.